# Where do I find the client id and client secret of an existing connected app?

Tags: api, oauth2, connected-apps

Where do I find the client id and client secret of an existing connected app?
The documentation talks about this information being provided when creating a new app, but what if my app already exists? I can't find this info.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just navigate ***Name > Setup > Create > apps*** and then click on the app you need. The page you load will contain those information under **API (Enable OAuth Settings)**.

Comment: fwiw in my interface I just searched in the left sidebar for "App Manager" and then at the top-right "New Connected App".

Comment: It is available only in Classic UI.

Comment: Answer posted on mid of 2014 so yah make sense :)

Answer (score 19):

In the Enterprise edition I am using, to find the client id and secret for an existing app, I had to go to Setup > App Manager > Down Arrow next to app name > View > look under 'API (Enable OAuth Settings)'.

This was very confusing as you'd think you could go to  Setup > Connected Apps > then click on the App name to see it... but nope, it wasn't there.  Nor was it there when editing the App.  Only through the process above could I find it.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, not sure if they changed settings, but now the "consumer key" and "consumer secret" can be found following these steps.

Comment: There's no such option as "App Manager" in the Setup menu, did you mean "Manage Apps"?

Comment: I no longer have access on the project I was working on when I answered this question but it sounds like perhaps they changed the name of the menu item from "App Manager" to "Manage Apps"

Comment: yep, it's Setup -> Apps -> App Manager (then as described). Or you can just type "App Manager" into Setup's global search box.

Answer (score 1):

From the Setup menu (not "Service Setup"), navigate to PLATFORM TOOLS -> Apps -> App Manager
[image]

Find your app in the list, then choose "View" from the small dropdown at the far right.

Answer (score 0):

First I navigated to: Build -> Create -> Apps. Here I see list of "Connected Apps".  (with respect to classic UI)

If you click on "Edit" or "Manage" it doesn't show client_id or secret. To see these details I had to click on the apps's name itself.