# Client Id and Client Secret

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity, client-id

A simple question : where can I find the client Id and the client Secret in Marketing cloud? I saw some doc about this but it was only on the previous version of marketing cloud Exact Target AppCenter like this one : [Where do I find the client id and client secret of an existing connected app?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40346/where-do-i-find-the-client-id-and-client-secret-of-an-existing-connected-app) . I'm using the fuelSDK for nodeJS in a custom activity in Journey Builder, and I need those to authentificate myself to marketing cloud APi. Thanks !

EDIT :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you log into the relevant Business Unit, Click Administration from the drop down under your user name.

Then Account > Installed Packages

You should see a list of installed packages, select the relevant package, you should then see the clientID and Secret.

Comment: Which one is the client ID and Secret pls ? I added an image of the package

Comment: It clearly indicated which one is the secret, so the other one is the...

Comment: Neither are the client keys and secrets to authenticate yourself with the SFMC API. I assume you may need to create a new component for a API integration if you don't already have one. That will give a API access.

Comment: You should look here if you have not done it yet: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot @NoorAlam, I just realise  I could create a API integration component thanks to you :)