# Not able to see client id and client secret in the connected app

Tags: rest-api, api, connected-apps, client-id

I have created a connected app with below configuration in Salesforce Developer edition:

[image]

But not able to see client id and client secret in the app.

I tried opening the connected app through **Setup->Manage Apps->Connected Apps**, in **Setup->Create->Apps** but no success.

Where can I get a client id and secret for my connected app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I find the client id and client secret of an existing connected app?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40346/where-do-i-find-the-client-id-and-client-secret-of-an-existing-connected-app). See the answer by Richard Buff

Comment: Enable OAuth Settings was not checked so the app was not showing the client id and client secret.

Comment: Yeah, the question is duplicate.

Comment: In [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40346/where-do-i-find-the-client-id-and-client-secret-of-an-existing-connected-app), it is nowhere mentioned that we need to enable the OAuth Settings, which was the major cause of the values not being shown in the connected app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the connected app.

Clicked on edit.

In **API (Enable OAuth Settings)**, checked **Enable OAuth Settings**:

[image]

Used *https://login.salesforce.com* **Callback URL**.

Added *Full access (full)* in **Selected OAuth Scopes**.

Now I am able to see the **Consumer Key** and **Consumer Secret**:

[image]